# Printing a list of records in F#

Tags: f#

I'm new in F# and I don't understand next error:

```
let g = 9.8
let v = 320.0
let a = 45.0
let iterations = List.unfold(fun x-> if x < 100.0 then Some(x,x+0.1) else None) 0.0
type point = {x:float;y:float}
let tPoints = List.map(fun t -> {x=v*t*cos(a); y=v*t*sin(a)-g*(t**2.0);})
for point in tPoints do
    printfn "%A" point
```

at line:

```
for point in tPoints do
```

The type '(float list -> point list)' is not a type whose values can be enumerated with this syntax, i.e. is not compatible with either seq<*>, IEnumerable<*> or IEnumerable and does not have a GetEnumerator method  fs

```
tPoints|>List.iter(fun p->printfn "%A" p)
```

in this way it's also doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tPoints` is not a list, but a function.

`List.map` takes two arguments - a function and a list, - and returns a list. You only gave it one argument, so the return value is a function that is still "waiting" for the second argument.

The type of that function is `(float list -> point list)` - that is, it expects an argument of type `float list` and will return a `point list`. You are trying to iterate over that function, and this is what the compiler tells you that you can't do: *cannot enumerate values of type float list -> point list*.

I guess you meant to pass `iterations` to it:

```
let tPoints = List.map(fun t -> {x=v*t*cos(a); y=v*t*sin(a)-g*(t**2.0);}) iterations
```